# Adobe AIR read .sol file of Flash Player

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, shared-objects

I have a problem with Shared Objects files when I need read the .sol of the Flash Player with a Adobe AIR application.

The path of the Flash Player Shared Objects is:

```
C:/Users/%username%/AppData/Roaming/Macromedia/Flash Player/#SharedObjects/%randomnumber%/localhost/
```

However, the path of the Adobe AIR Shared Objects is:

```
C:/Users/%username%/AppData/Roaming/%applicationname%/Local Store/#SharedObjects/#localhost/
```

How can I read a Flash Player Shared Object with Adobe AIR application?

**I tried:**

- Use the `FileStream` class to open the `.sol` file with the method `readObject`, but it does not work.
- Copy the `.sol` file to the Adobe AIR Shared Object path and read with `SharedObject`, but the `Error #2134: Cannot create SharedObject` occurs.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: You are not supposed to read SO this way at all. The **only** correct way to work with shared object is to connect to is with documented **var SO:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("object id", "local path");**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flash Player/AIR does not have a built in way to read a `.sol` file directly. Of course the `SharedObject` class is the way you're supposed to access SO data, but it comes with restrictions and as you noted reads from a specific known path, it cannot be used to parse any `.sol` file directly. To read a `.sol` file you would need to use `FileStream` then parse the `ByteArray` directly following the `.sol` format... of course `.sol` uses AMF to store the data so `readObject` should work for a portion, but the file format (header, etc) is its own format that must be parsed out. Unfortunately finding good documentation on the format is very hard. There are a bunch of SO readers out there already, you might be able to use one as a reference:

- http://blog.sephiroth.it/projects/shared-object-reader/
- http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=657620
- https://mariani.life/projects/minerva-air/